# Unexpected behaviour of from_logits in BinaryCrossentropy?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, image-segmentation, loss-function, logits

I am playing with a naive U-net that I'm deploying on MNIST as a toy dataset.
I am seeing a strange behaviour in the way the `from_logits` argument works in `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy`.

From what I understand, if in the last layer of any neural network `activation='sigmoid'` is used, then in `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy` you must use `from_logits=False`. If instead `activation=None`, you need `from_logits=True`. Either of them should work in practice, although `from_logits=True` appears more stable (e.g., [Why does sigmoid & crossentropy of Keras/tensorflow have low precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125924/why-does-sigmoid-crossentropy-of-keras-tensorflow-have-low-precision/52126567#52126567)). **This is not the case in the following example**.

So, my `unet` goes as follows (the full code is at the end of this post):

```
def unet(input,init_depth,activation):
    # do stuff that defines layers
    # last layer is a 1x1 convolution
    output = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1,(1,1), activation=activation)(previous_layer) # shape = (28x28x1)
    return tf.keras.Model(input,output)
```

Now I define two models, one with the activation in the last layer:

```
input = Layers.Input((28,28,1))
model_withProbs = unet(input,4,activation='sigmoid')
model_withProbs.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()) #from_logits=False since the sigmoid is already present
```

and one without

```
model_withLogits = unet(input,4,activation=None)
model_withLogits.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()) #from_logits=True since there is no activation
```

If I'm right, they should have exactly the same behaviour.

Instead, the prediction for `model_withLogits` has pixel values up to 2500 or so (which is wrong), while for `model_withProbs` I get values between 0 and 1 (which is right). You can check out the figures I get [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQkLD.png)

I thought about the issue of stability (`from_logits=True` is more stable) but this problem appears even before training ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9bdE.png)). Moreover, the problem is exactly when I pass `from_logits=True` (that is, for `model_withLogits`) so I don't think stability is relevant.

**Does anybody have any clue of why this is happening? Am I missing anything fundamental here?**

**Post Scriptum: Codes**

*Re-purposing MNIST for segmentation.*

I load MNIST:

```
(x_train, labels_train), (x_test, labels_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

I am re-purposing MNIST for a segmentation task by setting to one all the non-zero values `x_train`:

```
x_train = x_train/255 #normalisation 
x_test = x_test/255 
Y_train = np.zeros(x_train.shape)  #create segmentation map
Y_train[x_train>0] = 1   #Y_train is zero everywhere but where the digit is drawn
```

*Full `unet` network*:

```
def unet(input, init_depth,activation):

  conv1 = Layers.Conv2D(init_depth,(2,2),activation='relu', padding='same')(input)
  pool1 = Layers.MaxPool2D((2,2))(conv1)
  drop1 = Layers.Dropout(0.2)(pool1)

  conv2 = Layers.Conv2D(init_depth*2,(2,2),activation='relu',padding='same')(drop1)
  pool2 = Layers.MaxPool2D((2,2))(conv2)
  drop2 = Layers.Dropout(0.2)(pool2)

  conv3 = Layers.Conv2D(init_depth*4, (2,2), activation='relu',padding='same')(drop2)
  #pool3 = Layers.MaxPool2D((2,2))(conv3)
  #drop3 = Layers.Dropout(0.2)(conv3)

  #upsampling
  up1 = Layers.Conv2DTranspose(init_depth*2, (2,2), strides=(2,2))(conv3)
  up1 = Layers.concatenate([conv2,up1])
  conv4 = Layers.Conv2D(init_depth*2, (2,2), padding='same')(up1)

  up2 = Layers.Conv2DTranspose(init_depth,(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(conv4)
  up2 = Layers.concatenate([conv1,up2])
  conv5 = Layers.Conv2D(init_depth, (2,2), padding='same' )(up2)

  last = Layers.Conv2D(1,(1,1), activation=activation)(conv5)


  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=input,outputs=last)
```

Comment: any headway on this? I also switched to from_logits=True as recommended elsewhere but now my loss is stuck at 0.693 = ln(2).

Comment: For me it does not work with sigmoid on last node I also need ```from_logits = True```. Spent an hour scratching my head on this!